# Kubernetes / minikube can't ping pods in the same cluster, but nslookup works

Tags: docker, networking, dns, kubernetes, minikube

minikube version                                                                                                                                                                                        ⏎
minikube version: v0.22.3

I'm trying to setup various pods within a minikube instance. I'm running behind a corporate proxy which may explain some of this behavior.

I start minikube using the following

minikube start --docker-env HTTP_PROXY=http://corporate-proxy.com:80 --docker-env HTTPS_PROXY=https://corporate-proxy:80 --docker-env NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,192.0.0.0/8

otherwise it wont work at all. After building some images on docker I created a two services and two pods:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    name: app
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: image_app
      ports:
        - containerPort: 7777
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /codeage
          name: code-volume
          readOnly: false
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      tty: true
  volumes:
   - hostPath:
       path: /codeage
     name: code-volume
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: db
  labels:
    name: db
spec:
  containers:
    - name: db
      image: postgres
      ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
          name: db-data
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      tty: true
  volumes:
   - hostPath:
       path: /db-data
     name: db-data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: db
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: 'db-port'
    port: 5432
    targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    name: db
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    name: app
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - name: apport
     port: 7777
     targetPort: 7777
  selector:
     name: app
---
```

I'm unable to ping 'db' from within(ssh) the 'app' pod:

```
sh-4.2# ping db               
PING db.default.svc.cluster.local (10.0.0.116) 56(84) bytes of data.
From chicago11-rtr-3-v411.us.corporate.com (10.60.172.X) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
```

As you can see though nslookup worked and provided the correct clusterIP 10.0.0.116 and hostname 'db.default.svn.cluster.local'

I can ping the node itself. I cannot ping kube-dns...

Anyone have any ideas?

Is there an alternative to using the built in dns service?

Answer (score 1):

we can't ping the service IP address, you can telnet to the port `5432` defined in the service with service IP.

Comment: why can't you ping a service by `name.namespace` or ip address?

Comment: service ip act as proxy to route the traffic based on port number to pod. thats why we can't ping the service IP.  Service IP is not assigned to any network interface.

Answer (score 1):

@sfgroups answer is correct! ping was the wrong tool to use. Telnet or actually using psql worked. The actual problem was that my services weren't pointing to anything.

I updated my app pods to have the unique names and then updated the selector for the service.